# About the tag [computational-complexity]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Somebody created the tag [computational-complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-complexity). Do we need it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, [complexity-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory) is a synonym.

If you agree, please upvote for mapping [complexity-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory) ← [computational-complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-complexity) [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/complexity-theory/synonyms).